# Why does perl qx hang in Mojolicious::Lite but not in an ordinary program?

Tags: perl, mojolicious-lite, qx

(This is cperl 5, version 24, subversion 4 (v5.24.4c) built for x86_64-linux)
Ubuntu 18.04.

Below is a program that works. However, when I run this program from within
Mojolicious::Lite (version 6.04), it hangs.
Using top, I see that "tr" is the one eating all the CPU.
I have tried using cat instead of tr and it still hangs.
If I Control-C the Mojo code it prints the password then exits.
It is like tr is accepting the urandom bytes but not moving on to the fold
until I interrupt it.
But, this works in the ordinary script, not the Mojo one...

Anyone any ideas as to why?

Warmly

John

The script that works:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $pass_length = 3;
my $exec = qq{tr -cd "[:alnum:]" < /dev/urandom | fold -w$pass_length | head -n1};
print Dumper $exec;
my $pass = qx{$exec};
chomp $pass;
print Dumper $pass;
```

The Mojolicious Lite code that hangs:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

post 'testit' => sub {
    my $c = shift;

    my $pass_length = 3;
    # tr -cd '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w30 | head -n1
    my $exec = qq{tr -cd '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w$pass_length | head -n1};
    warn Dumper $exec;
    my $pass = qx{$exec};
    chomp $pass;
    warn Dumper $pass;
    return $c->render( json => { foo => 'bar'} );
};

app->secrets('foobar');
app->start;
```

Comment: Yes I can reproduce this. `head -1 /dev/urandom` works (gives one line of output) but not `head -1 /dev/urandom | tr-cd '[:alnum:]'` (it hangs). Interestingly `head -1 /dev/urandom | echo` gives a SIGPIPE : `write error: Broken pipe`, but `head -1 /dev/urandom | cat` works fine

Comment: @HåkonHægland Neither blocks for me on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. Nor does it make sense for one to block.

Comment: @HåkonHægland SIGPIPE is expected. It means `echo` exited before `head` wrote to the pipe, which is perfectly reasonable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```perl
sub gen_password {
   my ($pass_len) = @_;

   # We use sysread to avoid wasting entropy by over-reading.
   # We use :raw because we use sysread.

   state $bad_syms = {
      map { $_ => 1 }
         qw( 0 O I 1 l )
   };
   state $ok_syms = {
      map { $_ => 1 }
         grep !$bad_syms->{$_},
            'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9'
   };

   my $qfn = '/dev/urandom';
   open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn)
      or die("Can't open $qfn: $!\n");

   my $password = '';
   while (length($password) < $pass_len) {
      my $rv = sysread($fh, my $ch, 1);
      die("Can't read $qfn: $!\n") if !defined($rv);
      die("Can't read $qfn: Premature EOF\n") if !$rv;
      redo if !$ok_syms->{$ch};

      $password .= $ch;
   }

   return $password;
}
```

Benefits:

- More efficient.
- Fewer failure modes.
- Better error handling.
- Guaranteed to be the requested length.
- Avoids confusingly similar characters.

---

The following version wastes even less entropy, but requires a set of exactly 64 symbols:

```perl
use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );

sub gen_password {
   my ($pass_len) = @_;

   my $qfn = '/dev/urandom';
   open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn)
      or die("Can't open $qfn: $!\n");

   my $bytes = int( ($pass_len+3) * (3/4) );
   my $buf = '';
   while ($bytes) {
      my $rv = sysread($fh, $buf, $bytes, length($buf));
      die("Can't read $qfn: $!\n") if !defined($rv);
      die("Can't read $qfn: Premature EOF\n") if !$rv;
      $bytes -= $rv;
   }

   return substr(
      encode_base64($buf, '') =~
         tr/a-zA-Z0-9+\//a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z2-9!%^&*()/r,
      0, $pass_len,
   );
}
```

Comment: Excellent stuff as usual @ikegami. Would you care to hazard a guess why the Mojo stuff hangs? It was using morbo or hypnotoad, fwiw.

Comment: A nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why `tr` hangs when directly taking input from `/dev/urandom`. I was able to work around it by having an intermediate `cat` pipe before the `tr`. The following works for me:

```
my $exec = qq{head -1 /dev/urandom | cat | tr -cd '[:alnum:'] | fold -w$pass_length}
```

**Edit**:

If you want to generate a password of `$pass_length` characters, you can use `head -c` like this:

```
my $exec = qq{head -1 /dev/urandom | cat | tr -cd '[:alnum:'] | head -c $pass_length}
```

Comment: Interesting. However it doesn't quite work. The output I get is: `{
   "foo" : "ZF6\nnL4\nzwc\nSkM\nGuz\nXXC\nu86\n1Yb\nbVu\nFVj\nhpv\nhOa\niDP\nJAa\nicG\nynV\n4f1\nNi1\nOTD\nE2e\nwDs\n6nT\nx2B\ndc0\nFkN\nI"
}`

Comment: I also tried running the first program from the Mojo stuff and it still hangs. Curiouser and curiouser. Well I say curiouser, to someone that knows wtf is happening it is probably a no brainer :)

Comment: Hmm..I thought the `fold` command would split it into lines like that. What is your expected output then?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check if this is what you wanted

Comment: Spot on. Thank you. I had started to roll it in perl, but the above works fine. I would still like to know why the same code works differently though. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Note that you're not guaranteed to get `$pass_length alnum characters